# Meging two collections using Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Cypher query with two collections:

```
match (customer:CUSTOMER)-[r3:ADDRESS]->(addr:ADDRESS) 
with customer, doc, collect(addr) as addresses, collect(r3) as addr_prop
```

An example of the query result:

customer: {sss: 1123456}

addresses: [{street: A, number: B}, {street: C, number: D}]

addr_prop: [{last_update: 20160102}, {last_update: 20160112} ]

So I would like to have:

customer: {sss: 1123456}

addresses: [{street: A, number: B, last_update: 20160102}, {street: C, number: D, last_update: 20160112}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/syntax-collections.html#_list_comprehension) `[]` to iterate over the relationships and supply a map literal containing all the date you want. When having a relationship you can use `endnode` function to get to the target node.

Try this one:

```
match (customer:CUSTOMER)-[r3:ADDRESS]->(:ADDRESS) 
return customer, [x in collect(r3) | 
   { street: endnode(x).street, 
     number: endnode(x).number, 
     last_update: x.last_update }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan! I am using python to query neo4j. I will probably merge these two collections on python. And probably it is going to have more performance